Condensate Pump Intake Leak
Just noticed last night completely by accident there's lots of water coming out of the PVC going into the condensate pump. Likely to have been going on for some time. This red cap has been sitting there for over a year and assume this is the reason. Should it be back in? Why would it have popped out on its own?
https://imgur.com/a/2qXu3YS

Sure. Try putting the red plug back in. See if it solves the problem.
